# Wordpress installation issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed wordpress and added all the files to my web server. When I try to visit myWebsite/blog/wp-admin/instal.php I get the following error:

```
Warning: require(/customers/8/0/1/eitweb.co.uk/httpd.www/blog/wp-includes/functions.wp-
scripts.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/customers/8/0/1/eitweb.co.uk/httpd.www/blog/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 31 Fatal
 error: require(): Failed opening required '/customers/8/0/1/eitweb.co.uk/httpd.www/blog/wp-
includes/functions.wp-scripts.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in 
/customers/8/0/1/eitweb.co.uk/httpd.www/blog/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 31
```

I want to install word press and I do not know how to. I have seen some previous posts concerning similar problems, but nothing that resolves this one. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in file permissions... Give the following permissions to your wordpress directory.

Make your webserver the owner to the files. Example

```
chown -R www-data:wordpress /path/to/your/wordpress
```

... and then execute as root.

```
find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /path/to/your/wordpress/install/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am using Windows 7 OS if that helps?
My website address is eitweb.co.uk I am not sure how to use the code you have given me sorry.

Comment: Talk to your web hosting company... they will know what to do.